# how to apply the width and height of the img to multiple divs?

Tags: html, css

I want to make both the width and height of `#card-inner` and `c front` the same as the width and height of `c back` image, is there any way?

```html
    <div id="card_inner" onClick={()=> set(state => !state)}>
        <a.div className="c back" style={{ opacity: opacity.interpolate(o => 1 - o), transform }} >
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
        </a.div>
        <a.div className="c front" style={{ opacity, transform: transform.interpolate(t => `${t} rotateX(180deg)`) }} >
            <div>
                <Detail 
                    name= {name}
                    id= {id}
                    updated= {updated}
                    bio= {bio}
                    portfolio= {portfolio}
                />
            </div>
        </a.div>
    </div>
```

```css
.c {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding, addEventListener('resize, (){  /* your code here * / }),
addEventListener('load, (){  /* your code here * / })
and css Variables with class.

When loaded and resized, you can find out the height and width of your 'c back', and assign it to Variables from javascript.

you can  use css Variables in your class or css selector of your choice for #card-inner and c front
on risize

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
I'll try the way you told me :)

Comment: You tagged the question HTML, but that's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

card_inner block can have same width/height as c back just by default
c front can have same ones by setting it absolute position filling a parent.

```
#card_inner {
  position: relative;
}

.c.front {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

Also please remove

```
.c {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply!
I wrote position: absolute; because I wanted to apply the flip-card effect here!

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

I'll revise it again according to the method you told me :)